# Speed of every object within array changing upon collision

Tags: android, andengine

I am developing a game in AndEngine and I have an array of car sprties. I am checking when they collide with other objects on the screen, and when they do, the individual index of that array should have it's speed changed. however, every car on the screen's speed also changes.

any help would be appreciated. please find attached the code below:

```
this.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed) {
            for (int i = 0; i < rManager.getInstance().carArray.length; i++)
            {
                if(rManager.getInstance().carArray[i].getCarSprite().collidesWith(rManager.getInstance().iceArray[i].getIceSprite())) {
                    Log.e("test", "ice collision");
                    rManager.getInstance().carArray[i].setCarSpeed(3f);
                } else {
                    rManager.getInstance().carArray[i].setCarSpeed(0.5f);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void reset() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

updated code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rManager.getInstance().carArray.length; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < rManager.getInstance().iceArray.length; j++)
                    {
                        if(rManager.getInstance().carArray[i].getCarSprite().collidesWith(rManager.getInstance().iceArray[j].getIceSprite())) {
                            Log.e("log", "CAR COLLIDED WITH ICE LOL");
                            rManager.getInstance().carArray[i].setCarSpeed(3f);
                        } else {
                            rManager.getInstance().carArray[i].setCarSpeed(1f);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

updated code 2:

```
@Override
protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {

            for (int i = 0; i < rManager.getInstance().carArray.length; i++)
            {                       
                for (int j = 0; j < rManager.getInstance().iceArray.length; j++)
                {
                    if(this.getX() < (rManager.camera.getWidth() + this.getWidth())){
                        this.setPosition(this.getX() + (rManager.getInstance().carArray[i].getSpeed() + speedMod), this.getY());
                    } else {
                        this.setPosition(0 - this.getWidth(), this.getY());
                    }

                    if (rManager.getInstance().iceArray[j].getIceSprite().collidesWith(rManager.getInstance().carArray[i].getCarSprite()))
                    {
                        Log.e("log", "car collided with ice");
                        this.setPosition(this.getX() + (rManager.getInstance().carArray[i].getSpeed() + 2f), this.getY());
                    }
                }
            }               


            super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
    }
```

Comment: Would you please post the setCarSpeed() function and the declaration of the car speed variable? I have a suspicion that variable may be static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, notice that you are accessing to the array of (IceSprites) using the index of the cars. If you have a different number of these elements you can have exceptions.

Your code is only checking if each car collides with one ice sprite element. Is this what you want?

*rManager.getInstance().**carArray[i]**.getCarSprite().collidesWith(rManager.getInstance().**iceArray[i]**.getIceSprite())*

Maybe you want to check if your car collides with any ice element presented in your world. No? 
In that case you will need another loop for the ice elements.

I hope this helps,
Best Regards

Comment: hi pedro, thanks for the quick reply.

i have a bunch of cars and a bunch of ice sprites, and i want to check when there is any type of collision between any of them :)

Comment: i have better collision, but the same problem still persists. whenever there is a collision, all cars are affected! :(

Comment: Then on each update you need to peek a *collidable* element and test it against all *collideable* elements in your world. And do this for all elements. Notice, that you can avoid some tests of elements that you already tested it before in the same update.

Comment: hi pedro, i think i understand, but i am still having some issues. i've added the updated code testing all elements to the first post. unfortunately, not only am i still getting the same problem with all objcts within the car array changing if there is 1 collision, but some collisions with the ice aren't working. the log shows that they are being registered, but the speed of the car is not changing. im testing all possible elements, so it doesn't much too much sense. thanks!!

Comment: Notice that you are testing each car with all ice elements in the world. If your car has the speed 2f and it collides with the first ice element the speed will be 3f. Right? But when you try to test it with second ice element you car will not collide with it, then the speed will be 1f.

Comment: ah yes. thats a crucial error. speeds are being set correctly now. each car is now colliding properly with the other elements. the only thing i need to fix now is to stop all of the cars in the array from speeding up. even if 1 car collides with an element in the ice array, all of the cars in the car array will also speed up. final code added to original q. kind regards and thank you so much for the support